# Adding colorbars to clustered heatmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to replicate this type of plot (heatmap with colorbars as leaves)
[image: heatmap with colorbars as leaves]]

This is what I've done so far

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

#read data
fid_df = pd.read_csv(fid_file, index_col=[0])

# scale data
def scale(x):
    return np.math.log2(x+1)
fid_df = fid_df.applymap(scale)

# clustering colums
data_1D_X = ssd.pdist(fid_df.T, 'euclidean')
X = sch.linkage(data_1D_X, method='ward')
# clustering rows
data_1D_Y = ssd.pdist(fid_df, 'cityblock')
Y = linkage(data_1D_Y, method='ward')
#plot first dendrogram
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='left')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.71, 0.6, 0.2])
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(X)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# plot matrix
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
# sorts based of clustering
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = fid_df.values[idx1, :]
D = D[:, idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu)
axmatrix.set_xticks([])
axmatrix.set_yticks([])
```

Example:
[image: example]

However, I need to add colorbars that would show the initial groups of rows and columns. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It is not clear to me which colorbar you are talking about. Would you mind being more specific?

Comment: in the example above columns grouped/colored by ER factor I want to add something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 0.9))
ax2 = fig.add_axes((0, 0.9, 1, 0.1))
gridY, gridX = np.mgrid[0:10:11 * 1j, 0:10:11 * 1j]
ax1.pcolormesh(gridX, gridY, np.sqrt(gridX ** 2 + gridY ** 2))
randCol = ['red', 'blue']
for value in np.linspace(0, 10, 1001):
    ax2.axvline(value, color=randCol[np.random.default_rng().integers(2)])
ax2.set_xlim((0, 10))
ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=False, bottom=False, labelleft=False, left=False)
fig.savefig('so.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea i need to add one more axes. I thought there are easier way to do so.

Comment: @SaveliyBelkin No worries. There might be an easier way, but if it exists, I do not know about it. If you found my answer helpful, please feel free to [upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).